# How do i split an array based on subarray element state?

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js

I have an array consisting of sub arrays:

```
myArray  = [[info1, info2, info3, value1], [info1, info2, info3, value1], 
[info1, info2, info3, value1],.............]
```

I want to split the array into several arrays based on "value1". If value1 is above 1000 in more then 5 consecutive elements i want to create a new array:

```
mySubArray1 = [[info1, info2, info3, 1011], [info1, info2, info3, 
1012], [info1, info2, info3, 1011],.............]
```

and so if i discover a second series of elements where value1 is above 1000 in more then 5 consecutive elements i want to create another array:

```
mySubArray2 = [[info1, info2, info3, 3030], [info1, info2, info3, 
4000], [info1, info2, info3, 1700],.............]
```

What i have done is the following:

```
var j;
for (j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
if (array[j][3] < 1000 ) {

    console.log("below 1000");
}
else {
    console.log("above 1000");
}

}
```

This detects where value is above 1000, but now i need to sort it into new arrays, and i don't know how to start that process.

Comment: What are `info1, info2, info3`, etc? Are those all standalone variables too? (if you meant to use strings, strings need delimiters) You should also post the code you've tried that isn't working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do an Array.reduce to get the desired result:

I'm generating an array that should be like your input, the value of 'value1' will be between 995 and 1010.

```js
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

let myArray  = [...Array(100).keys()].map(n => ['info1', 'info2', 'info3', getRandomInt(995, 1010)]);

console.log("Input: ", JSON.stringify(myArray));

let subArray = [];
// Result will contain a list of our new subarrays.
let result = myArray.reduce((acc, val, index) => {

   if (val[3] >= 1000) { 
      subArray.push(val);
   } 

   if ((val[3] < 1000) || (index === myArray.length - 1) /* Handle the case when we're at the end of myArray */ ) {
       if (subArray.length > 5) { 
           acc.push(subArray);
       } 
       subArray = [];
   }
 
   return acc;
}, [])

console.log("Result:");
result.forEach( (subArray, n) => console.log(`Subarray ${n+1}: `, subArray));
```

Comment: Thanks. I partly understand this and it partly works. But now, if the lenght of the consequetiuve series is longer then 5, it will break the array regardless on subArray.length = 5 ? So if it is a series of 8 it will actually create a subarray with 5... (My goal in this case is to get all 8 in the same subArray) I think maybe something like this could solve it:                     if (subArray.length > 5 && val[3]<1000) {
        acc.push(subArray);
        subArray = [];
    }

Comment: I've updated the answer with new logic, it should create subarrays of 5+ items.

Comment: Thanks again! Series longer then 5 is now appended to subarrays. It might still have one issue: If the last value is supposed to go into the subarray, the last subarray will be disregarded because of: (index === myArray.length - 1)    ..............(I think).